# how to display an xml file as code in php?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to display an xml file in php like on the image:

[image: image of a random website]

I'm using php 7.0.3

Comment: 2 hours? `echo "<pre>$xmlstuff</pre>";` or `echo htmlentities($xmlstuff);` Also, `highlight_file("/path/to/file.xml");`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Are you trying to include the functionality of the collapse triangles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we tell the browser that it's about to get some XML:

```
header('Content-type:text/xml');
```

Then, we echo the content itself:

```
echo(file_get_contents('PATH_TO_YOUR_XML_HERE');
```